# How do you get the Eclipse Package Explorer to show files whose names begins with a . (period)?

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

When a folder in the Eclipse Package Explorer (one which is linked to a directory somewhere in the filesystem) contains files whose names begin with a . (period), those files do not appear. Can Eclipse be configured to show these files, and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the down-arrow in the package explorer (next to the editor linker).  Then you just change the filters.  Unmark the box that says '.*' resources.